# How do I generate a QR Code in JavaScript (shadowDom) and generate a data url for image?

Tags: javascript, qr-code, web-component

I'm having trouble finding a library that will work in a webcomponent shadowDom. The only one that seems to be highly recommended requires an "id" as a argument (it won't find the id because its in the shadowDom.

1. generate qr code from string (ie: url)
2. generate a data url for img tag to display

```
    this.id = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1));
    this.data = new QRCode().makeCode(this.id);
    //this.data = QR.encode(this.id);
    this.qrCode = btoa(this.data.toByteArray()));
```

Here's the library: https://taisukef.github.io/qrcode-generator/es/QR.js

Comment: Would be great if you actually link to that library you say doesn't work with shadowDOM. Even better, add a SO snippet with running.. ehm.. failing code.

Comment: https://taisukef.github.io/qrcode-generator/es/QR.js